# Python - txt to csv

Tags: python, csv, text

I am new to Python. I am trying to transfer data from a text file to a csv file. I have included a short description of the data of my text file and csv file. Can someone point me to the right direction of what to read up to get this done?

```
**Input Text file**
01/20/18 12:19:35#
TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN=0
TARGET_CENTER_ROW=0
TARGET_COLUMN=0
BASELINE_AVERAGE=0
#
01/21/18 12:19:35#
TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN=0
TARGET_CENTER_ROW=13
TARGET_COLUMN=13
BASELINE_AVERAGE=26
#
01/23/18 12:19:36#
TARGET_COLUMN=340
TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN=223
TARGET_CENTER_ROW=3608, 3609, 3610
BASELINE_AVERAGE=28
#
01/24/18 12:19:37#
TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN=224
TARGET_CENTER_ROW=388
TARGET_COLUMN=348
BASELINE_AVERAGE=26
#
01/25/18 12:19:37#
TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN=224
TARGET_CENTER_ROW=388
TARGET_COLUMN=348
BASELINE_AVERAGE=26
#
01/27/18 12:19:37#
TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN=223
TARGET_COLUMN=3444
TARGET_CENTER_ROW=354
BASELINE_AVERAGE=25
#

**Output CSV file**
Date,Time,BASELINE_AVERAGE,TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN,TARGET_CENTER_ROW,TARGET_COLUMN
01/20/18,9:37:16 PM,0,0,0,0
01/21/18,9:37:16 PM,26,0,13,13
01/23/18,9:37:16 PM,28,223,3608,340
                    0,0,3609,0
                    0,0,3610,0
01/24/18,9:37:16 PM,26,224,388,348
01/25/18,9:37:16 PM,26,224,388,348
01/27/18,9:37:16 PM,25,223,354,344
```

Reading up online I've been able to implement this.

```
import csv

txt_file = r"DebugLog15test.txt"
csv_file = r"15test.csv"
mylist = ['Date','Time','BASELINE_AVERAGE' ,'TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN', 'TARGET_CENTER_ROW','TARGET_COLUMN']
in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"))

with open(csv_file, 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(mylist)
```

Beyond this I was planning to start a for loop and read data till # as this would be 1 row, and then use the delimiter to find each '=' and insert the data into the appropriate location in a row list(do this by comparing the column header with the string prior to the delimiter) and populate the row accordingly. Do you think this approach is correct?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) for a nicer approach. You give it a list of headers and then you can give it data dictionaries which it will write for you. The writing portion would look like this:

```
import csv

csv_file = "15test.csv"
headers = ['Date','Time','BASELINE_AVERAGE' ,'TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN', 'TARGET_CENTER_ROW','TARGET_COLUMN']

with open(csv_file, 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, headers = headers)
    # data_dicts is a list of dictionaries looking like so:
    # {'Date': '01/20/18', 'Time': '12:19:35', 'TARGET_CENTER_COLUMN': '0', ...}
    wr.writerows(data_dicts)
```

As for reading your input, `csv.reader` won't be of much help: your input file isn't really anything like a csv file. You'd probably be better off writing your own parsing, although it'll be a bit messy because of the inconsistency of the input format. Here's how I would approach that. First, make a function to interpret each line:

```
def get_data_from_line(line):
    line = line.strip()
    if line == '#':
        # We're between data sections; None will signal that
        return None 
    if '=' in line:
        # this is a "KEY=VALUE" line
        key, value = line.split('=', 1)
        return {key: value}
    if ' ' in line:
        # this is a "Date time" line
        date, time = line.split(' ', 1)
        return {'Date': date, 'Time': time}
    # if we get here, either we've missed something or there's bad data
    raise ValueError("Couldn't parse line: {}".format(line))
```

Then build the list of data dictionaries from the input file:

```
data_dicts = []
with open(txt_file) as infh:
    data_dict = {}
    for line in infh:
        update = get_data_from_line(line)
        if update is None:
            # we're between sections; add our current data to the list,
            # if we have data.
            if data_dict:
                data_dicts.append(data_dict)
            data_dict = {}
        else:
            # this line had some data; this incorporates it into data_dict
            data_dict.update(update)
    # finally, if we don't have a section marker at the end,
    # we need to append the last section's data
    if data_dict:
        data_dicts.append(data_dict)
```